# getting detailed SQL logs from Heroku Cedar Stack

Tags: logging, heroku

What exactly needs to happen in order to get detailed SQL logs out of heroku cedar?

On our dev platform the log trail gives us lots of information including insite into the SQL which is being executed by activerecord. In production the information is much less detailed.

What do i need to do to get this SQL information when i run

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Is there a setting i need to send to heroku or something i need to put into my rails code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku's Logplex contains all logging statements from your application - there is no filtering of any kind.

By default, Rails does not log SQL statements in production so you'll need to bump your log level in `production.rb` to a level that is more suitable.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: simply uncommented the following:
config.log_level = :debug

Comment: I tried this to no avail.  Made the change in environments/production.rb and Heroku still refuses to log my SQL.  However, when I run locally with the same production.rb and RAILS_ENV=production, the sql gets logged just fine.

So the problem is *definitely* heroku.  Any ideas?  Thanks.